# Appending text to cell but stuck in loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

My problem is that my code doesn't work how I think it should work. I have Loop in my worksheet_change macro, and in that loop I want that if statement is correct (`MsgBox` button pressed Yes), what is written in that cell would have appended value at the end of that text.

But if I run this macro and I press Yes - cell value has the value at the end, but MsgBox comes right again, and I'm stuck in that loop... I'm new to VBA programming and syntax.

Can someone help me and explain my mistake?

**Code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rLockable As Range
Dim cl As Range

Set rLockable = Range("C13:J1000")
Set cl = Range("C13:J1000")
Set cele = Range("K13:K1000")
vardas = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Login").Range("O8").Value

Select Case True
    Case Not Intersect(rLockable, Target) Is Nothing
        'If target is within the range then do nothing
        If Intersect(rLockable, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="1234"
        For Each cl In Target
            If cl.Value <> "" Then
                check = MsgBox("Ar áraðyti áraðà? Koreguoti áraðo nebegalësite.", vbYesNo, "Áraðo iðsaugojimas")
                If check = vbYes Then
                    Target.Worksheet.Unprotect Password:="1234"
                    cl.MergeArea.Locked = True
                    cl.Value = cl.Value & " " + vardas
                Else
                    cl.Value = ""
                    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="1234"
                End If
            End If
            Exit For
        Next cl

    Case Not Intersect(Range("K13:K1000"), Target) Is Nothing
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="1234"
        For Each cele In Target
            If cele.Value <> "" Then
               cele.Offset(0, 2).MergeArea.Value = vardas
            End If
            Exit For
        Next cele
End Select

ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="1234"

End Sub
```

Comment: If this is event code you need to disable events before making changes to avoid re-triggering the code.

Comment: Please include the beginning of the code. If it is a worksheet_change event, the code will be an infinite loop

Comment: Yes its worksheet_change event, so i have to exclude somehow cells that already was written? im out of options at this moment...

Comment: Also `For Each cl In Target` makes no sense as you have already defined `cl` as another range (though won't cause any problems, possibly just unintended consequences).

Comment: Your for loops make no sense as you exit them before there can be a second iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before making a change to the worksheet you need to set enableEvent to false or the worksheet_change event will kick in again.

```
application.enableEvents=false
'change the worksheet
application.enableEvents=true
'resets the worksheet_change event
```

Comment: Including what the other members have mentioned, you do not require a loop just check target value .
`if target.value<>"" then`